# How to remove bottom border line with transparent background in my UICollectionView cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview

[image]

I tried to remove CollectionView Cell bottom border but no luck.
As attached is my sample code:-

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *gridcell = nil;

    MenuDetail_Cell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:MenuDetail_CellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

    cell.strMenuImage = self.imageArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.strMenuTitle = self.titleArray[indexPath.row];
    gridcell = cell;
    return gridcell;
}


- (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    if (!_collectionView) {

        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];

        _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
        _collectionView.delegate = self;
        _collectionView.dataSource = self;
        _collectionView.delaysContentTouches = NO;


            _collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, DCTopNavH, ScreenW, ScreenH  - DCBottomTabH);

        _collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

        //Cell
        [_collectionView registerClass:[MenuDetail_Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:MenuDetail_CellID];


        [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
    }
    return _collectionView;
}
```

Even I tried to apply `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex` but still the same.
Any idea? Sorry for my stupid mistake if any. Thank you.

Comment: @Dimple, my case is using objective c , so i hit `Property 'separatorColor' not found on object of type 'UICollectionVi` error here.

Comment: Try `cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;`

Comment: Its difficult to predict why this line is showing up can you add a pic of your view hierarchy using xcode's Debug View Hierarchy.

Comment: @nishithSingh, thanks for your idea, I found my prob via Debug View Hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UICollectionView do not have a separator like UITableView

It should be in your code somewhere, check out your storyboard of `MenuDetail_Cell` class

Comment: u  gave me some idea and i found the issue in my MenuDetail_Cell. Thanks!

Comment: exactly, my cell was not contain the default content view, apparently I deleted by mistake.